# Can "the light" see the seas of summer leaves?

Tags: meaning-in-context

There is this song called *Run in the Rain* (by Tom Grennan).

And part of the lyrics (Verse 2) goes like this:

> When the light can see
>   The seas of summer leaves
>   The melodies resolve and the eulogy agrees
>   Will you listen?
>   Will you listen?

In this context, what is the meaning of the word ***light***?

Considering the fact that the singer puts it as something that ***can see the seas of summer leaves***, is there any possibility that ***the light*** might be personification of God or something like that?

Or is it just that ***the light*** has purely literal meaning and the verb ***see*** denotes any other meaning?

Comment: I am sorry, but in spite of our name we do not do interpretation of song lyrics in English.SE.

Comment: You are asking a question about literary meaning.  The passage you cite is complicated.  The language is literary, and figurative.  You are right that to speak of light seeing is an example of personification.  Moreover, it is inverted.  Light enables us to see.  But instead it ‘sees’.  “sees the seas of summer leaves” conveys the not just what masses of trees look like but their sound in a gentle breeze:  this effect is called ‘assonance’.  “Will you listen?” is surely referring to this sound.  God?  Not necessarily.   do not know the poem.

Comment: It's poetry.  It can mean different things to different people.

Comment: The way I am interpreting it is "when the sun rises it is apparent.."  It is quite poetic, and possibly undecipherable.

Comment: https://genius.com/Tom-grennan-run-in-the-rain-lyrics

Comment: Thanks, everyone. It helped a lot.